# 302 found response

Tags: http-status-code-302

I have implemented ajax request to populate my drop down fields. It is working Fine but when I stay idle for some time and select some value in drop down the ajax request gets 302 found response. Is it due to session out. Please let me know the solution, can we do some setting that it will never get response as 302 found.

Answer (score 29):

The 302 status code indicates that the resource you are requesting has redirected to another resource. If this is behind some authentication, or requiring a session to be active then yes, it would follow that the session timing out is responsible for the ajax resource being called to redirect to possibly a login screen maybe.

I would seriously recommend using something like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com) or [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to track the requests being made.

Comment: I am using <auth-method>Basic</auth-method>, so how to get the login window, if session out

Comment: @Digbyswift
Its true and helped me. Its because of the session time out. thanks bro:)

Answer (score 1):

In your code you should check whether a session is available,
because when a GET/POST request is sent, there may be additional requests for images or other resources. Sessions won’t be available for those requests.

```
if (Context.Session != null)
{
    // your code
}
```