# Asynchronously query the database by using ajax and jquery and post the result back in codeigniter View

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I've struggeled alot with this .

I wanna send an ID in the CI model and get the returned value via CI controller

My view is

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
             function showsome(){
                 var rs = $("#s_t_item option:selected").val();
                 var controller = 'items';
                 var base_url = '<?php echo site_url(); ?>';

                 $.ajax({
                         url : base_url+ '/' + controller+ '/get_unit_item',
                     type:'POST',
                     contentType: 'json',
                     data: {item_id: rs},
                     success: function(output_string){
                         //$('#result_area').val(output_string);
                         alert(output_string);
                     }
                 });

             }

         </script>
```

My Controller method is

```
    public function get_unit_item()
      {
        $received = $this->input->post('item_id');  

        $query = $this->units_model->get_unit_item($received);
        $output_string = '';
        if(!is_null($query)) {
        $output_string .= "{$query}";
        } else {
        $output_string = 'There are no unit found';
        }
        echo json_encode($output_string); 
}
```

And my model function responsible

```
public function get_unit_item($where){
    $this->db->where('item_id',$where);
    $result = $this->db->get($this->tablename);
    if($result->num_rows()  >0 ){
        $j = $result->row();
        return $j->unit_item_info ; 
    }
}
```

Html codes

```
   <?php $id = 'id="s_t_product" onChange="showsome();"';
        echo form_dropdown('product_id[]', $products, $prod,$id); ?>
```

I tried to use the id only but failed to fire so passing a function onchange seems to pick the item and fire

Using firebug I can see that the post request sends item_id=2 but the response length is 0 and with php result code 302

POST 
[image]
RESPONSE
[image]

How can I achive this?(The model is loaded on the contructor)

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143438/302-found-response

Comment: You show us a request to getprice, however the ajax code you posted makes a request to get_unit_item. Please send us consistent information.

Comment: update and i think from the screen shot you can see that a request is a success

Comment: @NaszNjokaSr. Post your model code and your `if` condition must be something like **if(!empty($query))** or something like that, as you can see your if condition doesn't make any sense

Comment: @NarendraSisodia already updated but the same result. by the look of the returned value it looks like the call is being redirected to the login page

Comment: Try **print_r($result)** within model and check what result you are getting and use **console.log(output_string)** within `success` function that will provide detailed information

Comment: thanks @NarendraSisodia but it seems that the model does not get called up the page redirects to the login screen

Comment: @NaszNjokaSr. Post your html code too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying various approaches I have finally found what really is the problem and i think this might be the problem for all with the 302 found error. In this project (server) there're two systems within the same root and each has got its own codeigniter files. As seen above i was using

```
             var controller = 'items';
             var base_url = '<?php echo site_url(); ?>';
             url : base_url+ '/' + controller+ '/get_unit_item',
```

as the value for url but i tried to put the full url from the base and it worked so now it is

```
      url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/en/items/get_unit_item',
```

. I think for any one with the redirect issue the first thing to check is this

Answer (score 1):

Do slighly change your controller and model:

```
// Model 
public function get_unit_item($where){
    $this->db->where('item_id',$where);
    $result = $this->db->get($this->tablename);

    if($result->num_rows()  > 0 ) {
        $j = $result->row();
        return $j->unit_item_info ; 
    }
    else return false;
}


// Controller 
public function get_unit_item()
  {
    $received = $this->input->post('item_id');  
    $return = array('status'=>false);

    if( $query = $this->units_model->get_unit_item($received) ) {
        $return['status'] = true;
        // Add more data to $return array if you want to send to ajax
    }


    $this->output->set_content_type("application/json")
                 ->set_output(json_encode($return));
}
```

Check returned values in JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
     url : base_url+ '/' + controller+ '/get_unit_item',
     type:'POST',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: {item_id: rs},
     success: function( response ){
           if( response.status === true ) {
               alert('Everything Working Fine!');
               console.log( response );
           }
           else alert('Something went wrong in query!');
     }
 });
```

Comment: okay i did this and the result is something is wrong. actually if i check response.status it returns undefined. I think the model does not even get called the page is redirected to the login page right away

Comment: Where you have implemented the `showsome()` in html?

Comment: yeah its on a dropdown onchange